# How can I avoid an Optional nil error in UIImageView?

Tags: swift, machine-learning

I am trying to create a classification app and this UIImageView continues to produce an optional nil error. I'm not sure how to fix this and would greatly appreciate some support. Thanks.

I can have an icon or something like that but for some reason i haven't been able to successfully avoid this error.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Vision

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    
    //let imageCG = CGImag
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detectImageContent()
    }
    func detectImageContent() {
        Label.text = "Thinking..."
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50Int8LUT().model) else {return}
        // Create a vision request
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) {[weak self] request, error in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation], let topResult = results.first
                else {
                    fatalError("unexpected error")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.Label.text = "\(topResult.identifier) with \(Int(topResult.confidence)*100) % confidence"
            }
        }
            // LINE BELOW HAS THE OPTIONAL ERROR!
            guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self.myImg.image!) else { return}
            //Run googlenet places classifier
                    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage)
                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                        do {
                            try handler.perform([request])
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
        
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func savedPhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            myImg.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            myImg.image = pickedImage
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        detectImageContent()
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is myImg.image!.  There is no guarantee that myImg contains an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the issue by just replacing the force unwrap (`!`) with safe unwrap just as you're doing with the `guard let` declaration for `ciImage`. So, to fix your issue replace this:

```
guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self.myImg.image!) else { return}
```

With this:

```
guard let image = self.myImg.image, let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return }
```